# Preventing load of some images inside an *ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a list of images inside an *ngFor and I need to control the load of images as:

1. First load image with index number X
2. When all other images got loaded, fire a function

My goal is to first show the most important image as soon as possible without other images consuming the bandwidth.

I found some javascript solutions but they all were using document and window objects which are not allowed or recommended by angular team.

I have a very simple model and view. Is it even possible?

```
var images = ['src1','src2','src3','src4'];

<div *ngFor = "let img of images"> {{img}} </div>
```

Comment: How do you determine what the most important images are?

Comment: Why do you think document and window are not allowed or recommended?

Comment: Doesn't need to be determined programmatically, am I wrong about using document and window object?

Comment: I would avoid `document` and `window`, but if you have a good reason to use it, then why not? If you want to use angular-universal you need to be more cautious what you use, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't use these at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```ts
images = ['src1','src2','src3','src4'];
isImportantLoaded = false;
// set values to true for indexes that matches important images
// after all were set to false, set isImportantLoaded to true, 
// to get the non-important images loaded
importantImages = [false, true, false, true];

setLoaded(idx) {
  this.importantImages[idx] = false;
  var found = this.importantImages(true);
  if(found < 0) {
    this.isImportantLoaded = true;
  }
}

<ng-container *ngFor="let image of images, let i=index">
  <img (load)="setLoaded(i)" [href]="image" *ngIf="isImportant[i] || isImportantLoaded">
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Nice logic. Love that `ngIf` here.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<div *ngFor = "let img of images">
   <img [src]="img" (load)="onLoad($event)"/>
 </div>
```

in your component :

```
onLoad($event){
    //do something $event.target
}
```